# React context returns undefined on first login, but works on page refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I'm learning React Context & using it on a HOC so that i can see if a user is logged in or not throughout my app. Once logged in, i'm getting the users name from the context & displaying it in the header. It all worked fined before but all of a sudden now, the name is not displaying when the users first logs in, but displays normally as soon as you refresh the page.

Here's my HOC

```
import React, { createContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";

// Custom Components
import {getAuthenticatedUser} from '../../apis/usersApi'

// App global Context 
export const ContactManagerContext = createContext();

// Global context provider, provides context to all child components 
export const Provider = (props) => {
  // initial user authentication state
  const [isAuthenticated, setAuthentication] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    onLoad();
  },[]);

  // gets & sets user authentication state on component render
  const onLoad = async () => {
    const user = await getAuthenticatedUser();
    if(user) isAuthState(user);
  };

  const isAuthState = (user) => {
    setAuthentication(() => user)
  }

  // updates user state when logged in successfully
  const handleLogin = (user) => {
    console.log(user)
    isAuthState(user);
  };

  // updates userAuth state when logged out successfully
  const handleLogout = () => {
    isAuthState(null);
  };

  return (
    <ContactManagerContext.Provider
      value={{
        isAuthenticated,
        actions: {
          handleLogin,
          handleLogout
        },
      }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </ContactManagerContext.Provider>
  );
};

// Global context consumer
export const Consumer = ContactManagerContext.Consumer;

// wraps a component and provides context to it 
export default function withContext(Component){
    return function contextComponent(props){
        return (
            <ContactManagerContext.Consumer>
                {context => <Component {...props} context={context} />}
            </ContactManagerContext.Consumer>
        )
    }
}
```

Heres the component were im accessing the apps context

```
// Dashboard header containing users-name/logout button
export default function Header({ context }) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const history = useHistory();

  // logs user out and redirects them to '/'
  const logout = async () => {
    await logoutUser();

    context.actions.handleLogout();
    history.replace("/");
  };

  return (
    <Container maxWidth={false} className={classes.header}>
      <Container>
        {/* contacts banner */}
        <Grid className={classes.headerContainer} container alignItems="center">
          {/* User Icon */}
          <Grid item className={classes.headerItem}>
            <AccountCircle fontSize="large" />
          </Grid>

          {/* Users Name */}
          <Grid
            item
            className={`${classes.headerName} ${classes.headerItem}`}
          >
            <Typography variant="button"> {context.isAuthenticated.name} </Typography>
          </Grid>

          {/* Logout Button */}
          <Grid item>
            <Button
              style={{ color: "white" }}
              className={classes.logoutBtn}
              size="large"
              onClick={logout}
            >
              logout
            </Button>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Container>

    </Container>
  );
}
```

when using `console.log(context.isAuthenticated.name)` it prints 2 undefined. but as soon as I refresh the page, the users-name is printed only. So my question is, why would it only work fine after refreshing the page, instead of when first rendering it.

Comment: React Context only exists once it mounts try assigning the context to a local value with useaffect hook

Comment: @MosheSommers I tried that and its the same problem still. The way i'm using my context hoc is by wrapping the provider around my app component, so it mounts as soon as the app does & once i log in, i just change its state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to rerun your `useEffect` after there is a change. You use effect with the empty array as second argument is the equivalent of `componentDidMount()`.Therefore you need to tell when to re-render. You can do this by doing the following.

```
useEffect(() => {
    onLoad();
  },[isAuthenticated]);
```

Comment: Thanks that worked! I have to ask though if you can please explain why it is?? I assumed that on useEffect it would check if user is authenticated, which they obviously wont be. But then once they login I would set the state to that of the user & just get it from there. By doing what you suggested, would i just be calling onLoad() again and making a second api call & setting the state once again

Comment: `useEffect` is used to prevent unnecessary re-renders. Per the React's documentation it states that: "If you pass an empty array ([]), the props and state inside the effect will always have their initial values."  Your initial value would be `user not authenticated` so you would need to tell it to make sure to check for authentication change. I am not 100% sure on if it makes another call or not. I believe it shouldn't but instead re-renders component to match state

Comment: Okk so i tested out what you mentioned & you were right on the empty array part, the thing i noticed though is that if i do use `[isAuthenticated]` it gets stuck in a infinite loop where it keeps making the api calls inside of onLoad() :/ .. It's just confusing why changing the state from withing `handleLogin()` still wouldn't let the updated state to be accessible

Comment: That is weird maybe try adding an unsubscribe function to your `useEffect`. Also try adding `null` in your` initial user authentication state` and when you `setAuthentication` do `setAuthentication(user)`

Comment: dude i really appreciate the help. I already tried what you suggested and nothing seems to be working :/ im either getting an infinite loop to `onLoad()` or the same problem where it only displays on refresh. I think im just gonna post another question later on or something cause I really dont know what to do about this

Answer (score 1):

Okk so after hiring a freelancer to look at my code, we figured out what the error was. 
I'm still not entirely sure why, but in my header component on first render context was being delivered as {context: {}} but on second+ render it was being rendered as it should be.

so the solution we found was

```
  let userName = "";

  if(typeof context.isAuthenticated === 'object' )
    userName = context.isAuthenticated.name;
  else
    userName = context.isAuthenticated;
```

and displaying the userName variable

UPDATE ----------------------------------

After looking further into the issue, I realized what the core of my problem was. I forgot to send an object from the server, when the user firsts logs in so that's why it was appearing as undefined, & afterwards I was sending the correct info and that's why it was working. Main lesson i learned here is not to get caught up into thinking im using the new tech wrong & troubleshoot from the ground up

Comment: Glad you found solution! Just curious in your function `isAuthState()` your set has function inside like `setAuthentication(() => user)` I've always used just done it like `setAuthentication(user)`, what is your reasoning for that? Also you didn't give your `useState` an initial value is there a reason for that? Normally I have seen it even as `useState(null)`.

Comment: @AlvaroCastelan Thanks dude! i just updated my answer since i finally got to the root of the issue. But please correct me if i'm wrong in my reasoning here, but i normally do use `useState` just as you mentioned, unless i need the previous state. The only reason I used `useState(()  => user)` was because I thought that maybe it could be an async issues that was happening, and from my understanding using the arrow function helps resolve that when setting a state.

Comment: Also the reason I didn't set an initial value to `useState()` is actually laziness lol In my opinion is always good practice to initialize your variable so `useState(null)` would be the correct way of doing it. The one thing i noticed about JS is that if you don't initialized the variable it sees it as `undefined` & from my understanding undefined just means the value hasn't been assigned yet. So the definition matches since i don't yet have a value for it, and it kind of works like null, and it lets me be lazy and not write `null`. Not entirely sure if this can lead to problems though

Answer (score 0):

I face problem of after page refresh login context gone undefined. because I was set the logged in decision inside of "useEffect", and this will run only one time at initial time as I didn't give dependency. Then I resolved by taking the assign of state value outside of "useEffect". The demo code is as bellow.

[image]