# react how to change Navbar dynamically when you are logged in

Tags: reactjs, navbar

I have a navbar (component `navbarUser`) in the `App` component, and I would like when the user is logged in, to change the navbar to show logout and profile.

When the user is logged in the navbar doesn't change and I have an `useEffect` in the `App` component and in `NavbarUser`, but and if I make a manually refresh (F5) then the navbar change.

Where is my code problem? What is the solution in order to change dynamically the navbar?

I include a video: [video](https://youtu.be/oZW4UB7eU6s)

COMPONENT APP

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import logo from "./assets/logoBusca.png";
import "./App.css";
import { Route, Switch } from "wouter";
import logic from "./logic";
import Home from "./components/Home";
import Login from "./components/Login";
import Post from "./components/Post";
import NavbarUser from "./components/NavbarUser";

function App() {
  const [userLogged, setUserLogged] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const loggedIn = await logic.isUserLoggedIn;
      if (loggedIn) setUserLogged(true);
    })();
  }, [userLogged]);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <div className="images">
          <div className="logo">
            <a href="/">
              <img src={logo} alt="logo" />
            </a>
          </div>
          <div className="user_flags">
            <NavbarUser />
          </div>
        </div>
      </header>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/login">{() => <Login />}</Route>
        <Route path="/nuevabusqueda">{() => <Post />}</Route>
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

COMPONENT NAVBARUSER

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import userIcon from "../../assets/userIcon.png";
import logic from "../../logic";

export default function NavbarUser() {
  const [navbarUserIsLogged, setnavbarUserIsLogged] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const loggedIn = await logic.isUserLoggedIn;
      if (loggedIn) setnavbarUserIsLogged(true);
    })();
  }, [navbarUserIsLogged]);

  return (
    <>
      {!navbarUserIsLogged ? (
        <div className="navbar-item has-dropdown is-hoverable">
          <img src={userIcon} alt="user" />
          <div className="navbar-dropdown">
            <a href="/login" className="navbar-item" id="item_login">
              Login
            </a>
            <hr className="navbar-divider" />
            <a href="/registro" className="navbar-item" id="item_register">
              Registro
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div className="navbar-item has-dropdown is-hoverable">
          <img src={userIcon} alt="user" />
          <div className="navbar-dropdown">
            <a href="/datos" className="navbar-item" id="item_login">
              Perfil
            </a>
            <hr className="navbar-divider" />
            <a href="/user" className="navbar-item" id="item_register">
              Logout
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

COMPONENT LOGIN

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useLocation } from "wouter";
import logic from "../../logic";
import "./index.css";

export default function Login() {
  const [messageError, setMessageError] = useState("");
  const [, pushLocation] = useLocation();

  async function handleOnSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const {
      email: { value: email },
      password: { value: password }
    } = e.target;
    e.target.reset();

    try {
      await logic.loginUser(email, password);
      pushLocation("/nuevabusqueda");
    } catch (error) {
      setMessageError(error.message);
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      {messageError && (
        <div className="message-error">
          <p>{messageError}</p>
        </div>
      )}
      <section className="hero is-fullwidth">
        <div className="hero-body">
          <div className="container">
            <div className="columns is-centered">
              <div className="column is-4">
                <form id="form" onSubmit={e => handleOnSubmit(e)}>
                  <div className="field">
                    <p className="control has-icons-left">
                      <input
                        className="input"
                        name="email"
                        type="email"
                        placeholder="Email"
                        required
                      />
                      <span className="icon is-small is-left">
                        <i className="fas fa-envelope"></i>
                      </span>
                    </p>
                  </div>
                  <div className="field">
                    <p className="control has-icons-left">
                      <input
                        className="input"
                        name="password"
                        type="password"
                        placeholder="Password"
                        required
                      />
                      <span className="icon is-small is-left">
                        <i className="fas fa-lock"></i>
                      </span>
                    </p>
                  </div>
                  <div className="field">
                    <p className="control">
                      <button className="button is-success">Login</button>
                    </p>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <a href="/registro">
                      ¿Aún no estás registrado? Acceso para registarte
                    </a>
                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </>
  );
}
```

LOGIC

```
import buscasosApi from "../data";

const logic = {
  set userToken(token) {
    sessionStorage.userToken = token;
  },

  get userToken() {
    if (sessionStorage.userToken === null) return null;
    if (sessionStorage.userToken === undefined) return undefined;
    return sessionStorage.userToken;
  },

  get isUserLoggedIn() {
    return this.userToken;
  },

  loginUser(email, password) {
    return (async () => {
      try {
        const { token } = await buscasosApi.authenticateUser(email, password);
        this.userToken = token;
      } catch (error) {
        throw new Error(error.message);
      }
    })();
  }
};
export default logic;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a global authentication context so that all your components can successfully be aware of the changes that take place w.r.t to login/logout.

Currently what's happening is that even though the user logs in successfully, the `NavbarUser` component is not aware of that happening since there is no global **state** in your app based on which your `NavbarUser` can make a decision to change it's own **state** or not.

The following statement is just a one time operation anyway since `navbarUserIsLogged` is local to `NavbarUser` component and will only change post first render of component so this `useEffect` is not essentially going to ever run again and again solely based on `navbarUserIsLogged` because it's never changing. The change you require is a **global state change**.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const loggedIn = await logic.isUserLoggedIn;
      if (loggedIn) setnavbarUserIsLogged(true);
    })();
  }, [navbarUserIsLogged]);
```

React **Context** API solves this problem for us. Imagine having a **context or global state object** in which one of the key is `isAuthenticated`.

Your `NavbarUser` can now subscribe to the changes happening in that **global state** and whenever it changes, your `NavbarUser` component can re-render based on it:-

```
/* Suppose AuthContext is our global Context for giving us the global
 state or context object. We are de-structuring the isAuthenticated key 
from that object here. Suppose the value of isAuthenticated changes in 
global state so that will get informed to our component which uses useContext */

const {isAuthenticated} = useContext(AuthContext)
```

Now based on that `isAuthenticated` you can directly render the Navbar for authenticated user or an unauthenticated user.

Currently even though you are saving relevant tokens inside the `localStorage`, the components across your App aren't aware of those changes happening. On page refresh, the `localStorage` is simply read again.

There are ways to even make your current implementation work by passing the `setUserLogged` **state updater** function to each of your child components as a prop and triggering the update from them so that the `App` and it's every child get's re-rendered but it's **not a good way** to go about things. Make use of **Context API** here.

The following answer discusses a **Context API** implementation - [React context returns undefined on first login, but works on page refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61761348/react-context-returns-undefined-on-first-login-but-works-on-page-refresh)

As always refer React docs for more reference. Sharing the `useContext` one here - https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext

Answer (score 0):

Create two components

```
<NavLoggedIn>
//Logged in links and styling goes here
<NavLoggedIn>]

<NavPublic>
//Logged out links and styling goes here
<NavPublic/>
```

Finally, in your Navbar component, do this:

```
const Navbar = () => {
    return (
            <>
                
                        {!isAuth() ? <NavLoggedIn /> : <NavPublic />}
                
        </>
    );
};
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I have the same problem, don't refresh the navbar